# Couldn't find Event with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have developed an app where a user can log in and view their events. The event can be clicked on and in that events show page you can add songs. The problem I am having is that when you click submit after filling out the song field it gives me an error because it can't find the event id that the songs are adding to. I have defined a current_event variable in my method but still no luck :(. I feel like once I can get past this my application will work, and I won't need to ask so many questions about this one particular app lol.
Here is my songs controller:

```
class SongsController < ApplicationController

    def create
            current_event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @song = current_event.songs.build(songs_params)
        if @song.save
            flash[:success] = "Success"
            redirect_to root_url
        else
            flash[:error] = "Fail"
        end

    end

    def destroy
    end
    private

      def song_params
        params.require(:song).permit(:artist, :title, :genre)
      end
end
```

Song form:

```
<%= form_for Song.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :artist %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :genre %>

  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'welcome#index'
  get  '/signup', to: 'users#new'
  get  '/signup', to: 'users#create'

  get  '/login',  to: 'sessions#new'
  post  '/login',  to: 'sessions#create'
  get   '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'
  get '/account', to: 'users#show'

  resources :users
  resources :events 
  resources :songs

end
```

Thanks again for all the help and support I've gotten from everyone :D

Comment: What is the value given by `params[:event_id]` ? Try in `rails console` if you have any event record for that event id or not.

Comment: How would I go about checking that in the rails console? What sort of commands would I need to execute?

Comment: Check your server log when you submit the form .

Comment: It's assigning the song to a event id of nothing

Comment: I would assume then I would have to make the user also enter in an event along with a song

Comment: Add your form to question where you are adding a song to an event.

Comment: I added the song form to my question, I guess this isn't nesecarilly adding a song to an event rather just adding a song on the event page. I have this form rendered on the event page but no event id is ever being passed to the songs

Comment: can we see the routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nee to pass your event id in the following form:

```
<%= form_for Song.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :event_id, value: @event.id %>     #assuming you have @event defined in show action
  <%= f.text_field :artist %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :genre %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

In your controller:

```
class SongsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        current_event = Event.find(micropost_params[:event_id])
        @song = current_event.songs.build(songs_params)
        if @song.save
          flash[:success] = "Success"
          redirect_to root_url
        else
          flash[:error] = "Fail"
        end
    end

    def destroy
    end
    private
      def micropost_params
        params.require(:song).permit( :event_id,:artist, :title, :genre)
      end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now it is giving me another error. Saying songs_params is undefined. When I defined it in the private section. I mistakigly named it micropost when it should be called songs but it still doesn't work

Comment: You sir are a life saver! I just misspelled the song_params method lol